# use different colour in username in transcript

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, jsx

I have a usecase where I want to show the transcript along with the video with the people name who is speaking in the video.

So I want to set the different colours for each user in the video. the number of user can also vary from one video to another and for each user colour should also be unique.

Could you please let me know if there is any library which I can reuse here.

I am using react 16+ version for UI rendering part.

Comment: You can do it by generating random hex code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use Math.random() function for this use case. But you have to check background of text so text is visible easily.

```
var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
```

[Here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/random-hex-color/) you can check for more information

Comment: Sure will test it and get back. Thanks.